# Jenkins command execution failed

Tags: svn, jenkins

This is the weirdest thing.  I had a build successfully running.  Then I ran it again without changing anything in the configuration and it fails after pulling files from SVN.

```
FATAL: command execution failed
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node-4.2.6/.npmPackages
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:255)
    at hudson.FilePath$19.invoke(FilePath.java:1425)
    at hudson.FilePath$19.invoke(FilePath.java:1422)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.FilePath.delete(FilePath.java:1422)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstaller.performInstallation(NodeJSInstaller.java:149)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:108)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation.forNode(NodeJSInstallation.java:60)
    at jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NpmPackagesBuildWrapper$2.launch(NpmPackagesBuildWrapper.java:68)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:95)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:919)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:671)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It was already building with that version of node, and the folder it's referencing has rwx permissions for the user I am running the job with.  It's occurring between the step where I do an "svn update" and the step where I run a custom shell script.  I disabled the shell script to see if that was the problem, but I still get the same error.  So I'm thinking this is a Jenkins problem and don't know what the reason is for this.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to node 4.2.0 from 4.2.6 solved the problem.  I still don't know why it built with 4.2.6 successfully before and failed all of a sudden.